# Why after I set python-mode indent=1 I still can't get my code indented automatically when I am coding python

Tags: macos, vim, indentation, macvim, vim-plugin

So recently I watched a youtube video about "using vim as a python editor" and I decided to use it. It's the first time I use Vim. My System is OS X 10.9.5 and I am using MacVim. So I added following code to my gvimrc file.

```
    " Setting for python-mode"
    map <Leader> g :call RopeGotoDefinition() <CR>
    let ropevim_enable_shortcuts = 1
    let g:pymode_rope_goto_def_newwin = "vnew"
    let g:pymode_rope_extended_complete = 1
    let g:pymode_breakpoint = 0
    let g:pymode_syntax = 1
    let g:pymode_syntax_builtin_objs = 0
    let g:pymode_syntax_builtin_funcs = 0
    let g:pymode_indent = 1
    map <Leader> b Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() #BREAKPOINT<C-c>


    " ???set completeopt = longest,menuone"
    function! OmniPopup(action)
       if pumvisible()
            if a:action == 'j'
                return "\<C-N>"
            elseif a:action == 'k'
                return "<\C-P>"
            endif
        endif
        return a:action
        endfunction

    inoremap <silent><C-j> <C-R>=OmniPopup('j')<CR>
    inoremap <silent><C-k> <C-R>=OmniPopup('k')<CR>

    set nofoldenable
```

So I should actually invoke the indentation about python using this code: `let g:pymode_indent = 1`. But when I create a new Python file and use it to code Python. I still can't get the indentation to work.

I don't know anything about how to set up gvimrc file and I am just copy the code from that video. What went wrong? Thx!

Comment: [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) is a vim plugin. Did you install it?

Comment: Yes I did installed it. I installed a pathogen first. And then I download python-mode and put it in the bundle.

Comment: And do you have `filetype indent plugin on` in your `vimrc`?

Comment: OH!!!! That's exactly what I need. It worked. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing `filetype plugin on` in your `vimrc`. This will enable vim to identify the type of file you're editing and run plugins (and maybe some extra stuff) accordingly.

You can read more [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#filetypes) about filetype detection and plugins, or using `:help filetype`.